# magento 2 model override Issue

Tags: magento2, overrides

Right now I am trying to override the default class of Magento 2 due to some my custom requirement but couldn't succeed, don't know why what I have done wrong here. May be someone can help me to the right direction.

For this I have written this code in my system,

```
<preference for="Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection" type="COMPANY_NAME\MODULE_NAME\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\CatalogSearch\Collection"/>
```

and I want to override this class,

```
Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection
```

**EDIT**

`di.xml` `[app\code\COMPANY_NAME\MODULE_NAME\etc\di.xml]`

---

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">    
    <preference for="Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection" type="COMPANY_NAME\MODULE_NAME\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\CatalogSearch\Collection"/>   
</config>
```

---

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried to give permission for new added file "Collection.php" ?

Comment: Yes @Krupali permission is correct :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I found the solution by my self, Actually It create an Issue because module `CatalogSearch`use this class as `virtualType` in

`vendor\magento\module-catalog-search\etc\di.xml`

```
<virtualType name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\SearchCollection" type="Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="searchRequestName" xsi:type="string">quick_search_container</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

So we need to write `virtualType` class Instead of direct Magento search collection, like

```
<preference for="Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\SearchCollection" type="YOUR_COMPANY_NAME\YOUR_MODULE_NAME\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection" />
```

Comment: Hi @KeyurShah I had face same issue and M233 EE and same solution added but not working? Do you know why?

Comment: To be honest, I did not test with M233 EE, but it should work. after changing the `di.xml` did you remove `generation` directory?  and run the `di:compile` command? @RohanHapani

Comment: Yes. Already did. But, still no any result.

Comment: This class file called instead of custom : Magento\CatalogStaging\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection\Interceptor

Comment: Need to check this, but are you sure that this class also has `VirtualType`?

Answer (score 1):

I test this code it is working for me file location **etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection" type="Spacename\Moduelname\Model\Rewrite\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection" />
</config>
```

Check if you missed something else.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried the same thing that It is seems not working for me ? (:

Comment: @KeyurShah i think problem with you di.xml can you share the complete file also tell me is your module listed in admin?

Comment: I am using this in frontend. And check my edits @Qaisar

Comment: @KeyurShah what is your class path it must be `Accenture\Product\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\CatalogSearch\Collection.php` also don't understand the `frontend` are you using `etc/frontend/di.xml`?

Comment: Yes, just changed the path, still no luck,and I am using this file for frontend only. @Qaisar

Comment: I found the solution, please check answer @Qaisar, and +1 from your effort, thanks :)